# Check if viewcontroller presents another one from it's parent VC

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a Viewcontroller that presents another one if I press a button. I want to detect if it presents the other viewcontroller, but from a parent VC, that has reference to this viewcontroller. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a notification observer on your parent view controller and post a notification from the displayed child view controller to notify the observer.

Answer (score 1):

We want A to know when C has been presented.

```
A -> B -> C
```

You can use delegate method to interact with parent VCs with one-to-many relationship.

```
protocol BDelegate: class {
  func BVCDidPresentCVC(_ BVC: B)
}

class B {
weak var delegate: BDelegate?
func presentCVC() {
   delegate?.BVCDidPresentCVC(self)
}
}

extension A: BDelegate {
  func BVCDidPresentCVC(_ BVC: B) {
    // A knows B presented to C
  }
}
```

If you want a many-to-many relationship (Many VCS to know that C has been presented), use notifcations

```
class A {
  func setupNotifications() {
    // A.observeNotifcationCVCPresented
  }
}

Class B {
  func presentCVC() {
    //Notification.notifyCVCPresented
  }
}
```